# AWS SDK GO JSON Unmarshal Nested Response

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, go, unmarshalling, aws-sdk-go

I am trying to leverage the AWS GO SDK to retrieve a list of all AWS Secret Manager secrets i have access to "SecretList" and then return the nested ARN and Name of each for a future function to loop over. The issue pops up when i try to unmarshal the response that i believe to be JSON but maybe its in another format that im not aware of.

Response

```
{
  SecretList: [{
      ARN: "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-2:12345676879:secret:service1/secret-1-example-DLGoLU",
      CreatedDate: 1990-09-01 23:26:47.717 +0000 UTC,
      LastAccessedDate: 1990-10-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC,
      LastChangedDate: 1990-10-01 00:39:08.623 +0000 UTC,
      Name: "service1/secret-1-example",
      SecretVersionsToStages: {
        d35edf0b0-232a-4df2-a723-c873ad5b5ec52: ["AWSCURRENT"]
      }
    },{
      ARN: "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-2:12345676879:secret:service-2/example-2-TXAGC3",
      CreatedDate: 1990-10-01 23:58:32.279 +0000 UTC,
      LastAccessedDate: 1990-10-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC,
      LastChangedDate: 1990-10-01 02:22:02.525 +0000 UTC,
      Name: "service-2/example-2",
      SecretVersionsToStages: {
        41b456565452-91b8-41e0-a0d5-ac34356a221f3da: ["AWSCURRENT"]
      },
      Tags: [{
          Key: "Team",
          Value: "team"
        },
          Key: "Name",
          Value: "service-2"
        }]
    }]
}
```

GO Code

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/awserr"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/secretsmanager"
)

func getSecretManager() *secretsmanager.SecretsManager {
    sess := session.Must(session.NewSessionWithOptions(session.Options{
        SharedConfigState: session.SharedConfigEnable,
    }))
    return secretsmanager.New(sess)
}

// SecretsList ...
type SecretsList struct {
    SecretList []struct {
        ARN  string `json:"ARN"`
        Name string `json:"name"`
    } `json:"SecretList"`
}

func main() {
    svc := getSecretManager()
    input := &secretsmanager.ListSecretsInput{}
    result, err := svc.ListSecrets(input)
    if err != nil {
        if aerr, ok := err.(awserr.Error); ok {
            switch aerr.Code() {
            case secretsmanager.ErrCodeInvalidParameterException:
                fmt.Println(secretsmanager.ErrCodeInvalidParameterException, aerr.Error())
            case secretsmanager.ErrCodeInvalidNextTokenException:
                fmt.Println(secretsmanager.ErrCodeInvalidNextTokenException, aerr.Error())
            case secretsmanager.ErrCodeInternalServiceError:
                fmt.Println(secretsmanager.ErrCodeInternalServiceError, aerr.Error())
            default:
                fmt.Println(aerr.Error())
            }
        } else {
            // Print the error, cast err to awserr.Error to get the Code and
            // Message from an error.
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
        }
        return
    }
    var secrets SecretsList
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(result.String()), &secrets)
    fmt.Println("SecretList: ", secrets.SecretList[0])
    // json.Unmarshal([]byte(result.String()), &secret)
    // fmt.Println("Secret: ", secret)

    // fmt.Println(secret)
    // fmt.Println(result)
}
```

Comment: Might be a casing issue in your `SecretList` struct: `Name string`
Additionally you don't need the `json:"ARN"` or `json:"SecretList"` because the names match the fields.

Comment: JSON does not have a `Date` type so the date values in your response are not valid JSON:
`CreatedDate: 1990-09-01 23:26:47.717 +0000 UTC`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to perform a JSON Unmarshal at all to retrieve the ARN values. The documentation states the contract of [`ListSecrets`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/secretsmanager/#SecretsManager.ListSecrets) is as follows:

```
ListSecrets(input *ListSecretsInput) (*ListSecretsOutput, error)
```

Looking at the [`ListSecretsOutput`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/secretsmanager/#ListSecretsOutput) object, there is a nested slice of type [`SecretListEntry`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/secretsmanager/#SecretListEntry) which contains the ARN of the Secret, the name of the Secret, etc. Most SDK functions in Golang follow a similar format.